# objects in array no index position

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have an array which is a parsed xml feed which i want to add to another array using the code....

```
int insertIdx = [blogEntries count];

for (RSSItem *nextItem in feedItems) {          

    [blogEntries insertObject:nextItem atIndex:insertIdx];               

    //[blogEntries addObject:nextItem];

insertIdx += 1;

}
```

For some reason all of the objects in the blogEntries array all have an index of 0, when i slog them all out using...

```
for (RSSItem *nextItem in blogEntries)

    NSLog(@"title - %@, pos - %i", nextItem.title, [blogEntries IndexOfObject:nextItem]);
```

do you know why the index might not be updating?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How many `blogEntries` are there? Why are you using `insertObject:atIndex:` instead of `addObject:`? Are you actually using `indexOfObject:`, not a method you've created called `IndexOfObject:`?

Comment: Do not ignore compiler warnings. The `%i` format should in all likelihood be `%ld`, and then it should show the correct index values.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `addObject:` instead of `insertObject:atIndex`?

Are you sure that objects are different as:

[indexOfObject:
Returns the lowest index whose corresponding array value is equal to a given object.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject%3a)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to refrain myself On the Topic of adding many item at once into a NSMutableArray, I do prefer to use this method :

`- (void)addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)otherArray`

it remove that useless `for` loop. (unless you need to do some other work in that loop)

And as of your problem, viperking have a big hint about a possible problem you may be facing. (if that is the case you may need to validate your `isEqual:` method.